# PostgreSQL Group By not working as expected - wants too many inclusions

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a simple postgresql table that I'm tying to query. Imaging a table like this...

```
| ID | Account_ID | Iteration |
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 100        | 1         |
| 2  | 101        | 1         |
| 3  | 100        | 2         |
```

I need to get the ID column for each Account_ID where Iteration is at its maximum value. So, you'd think something like this would work

```
SELECT "ID", "Account_ID", MAX("Iteration")
FROM "Table_Name" 
GROUP BY "Account_ID"
```

And I expect to get:

```
| ID | Account_ID | MAX(Iteration) |
|----|------------|----------------|
| 2  | 101        | 1              |
| 3  | 100        | 2              |
```

But when I do this, Postgres complains:

```
ERROR: column "ID" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Which, when I do that it just destroys the grouping altogether and gives me the whole table!

Is the best way to approach this using the following?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Account_ID") "ID", "Account_ID", "Iteration"
FROM "Marketing_Sparks"
ORDER BY "Account_ID" ASC, "Iteration" DESC;
```

Comment: The Postgresql proprietary `distinct on` solves that nicely and is the recommended method. Otherwise a bit of sql foo is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GROUP BY statement aggregates rows with the same values in the columns included in the group by into a single row.  Because this row isn't the same as the original row, you can't have a column that is not in the group by or in an aggregate function.  To get what you want, you will probably have to select without the ID column, then join the result to the original table.  I don't know PostgreSQL syntax, but I assume it would be something like the following.

```
SELECT Table_Name.ID, aggregate.Account_ID, aggregate.MIteration
    (SELECT Account_ID, MAX(Iteration) AS MIteration
    FROM Table_Name
    GROUP BY Account_ID) aggregate
LEFT JOIN Table_Name ON aggregate.Account_ID = Table_Name.Account_ID AND 
    aggregate.MIteration = Tabel_Name.Iteration
```